# Blur event of div doesn't disturb input click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made blur effect for div (using tabindex=1) but later I've added input inside div:

```
<div id="d1" tabindex='2'>
    <input id="i1" type='text' tabindex='1'/>
</div>
```

I've added click handler for input and click+blur handlers for div:

```
 $('#i1').click(function(e){
    alert($(e.target).is('#i1, input'));
});

$('#d1').click(function(){
    alert('div clicked');
});

$('#d1').blur(function(e){
    alert($(e.target).is('#i1, input'));

});
```

But as you can try when I click on the div and then click on the input only div events are happened.

Click event and then blur effect.

It seems that it doesn't see input when blur effect of the div container is happend.

Could you please advice how to fix it.

The JSfiddle code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/z1987/gpkro53o/

Comment: You may be able to add `.parent()` before the .blur() to fix your issue. `$('#d1').parent().blur(function(e){...}`

Answer (score 0):

it does see the input, but the alert functionality is weird.  check the console of this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gpkro53o/1/

also, you want to add `e.stopPropagation()` to your input `click` event so that it wont trigger the `div` events

the console log for when you click on the div and then the input is:

```
div clicked
div blurred
input
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But maybe you know how to avoid blur effect in this case. I thought that input is the part of div and it must not cause the blur event

Comment: oh, so when you click on the div and then on the input, you dont want "div blurred", you only want "input"?

Comment: yes. I want for example hide div by blur. But if I click on the input I don't want to hide this div.

Comment: Oops sorry, not 'when I click on div and thet on the input' But when I 'click on the input which in the div'. Because in this case the blur event of div is prior

Comment: sorry, im still confused as to what you're desired functionality is